# Structure of $p$-torsion groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group whose elements have order a power of certain prime $p$, suppose the $p$-torsion elements are finite, must $A$ be of the form $$(\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)^{\oplus r}\oplus F$$ where $F$ is a finite group?

Comment: If the elements have prime power order they are already all torsion (have finite order), so I don't know what you mean by "p-torsion points are finite." Anyway, what about $\bigoplus \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$? That is not of that form. (Also, a more recognizable form for the $p$-Prufer group $\Bbb Z(p^\infty)$ that doesn't use $p$-adic numbers would be the quotient of additive groups $\Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z$.) Edit: oh, do you mean their are finitely many elements with order $p$? The term "injective hull" comes to mind but not sure if it can be used.

Comment: @arctictern Sorry I should say elements of order $p$ is finite, or elements annihilated by $p$ is finite.

Comment: (The *number* of elements of order $p$ is finite, not the elements themselves.) Seems like it should be true.

Comment: It is similar to the Proposition 2.1 by R. Greenberg in _Arithmetic Theory of Elliptic Curves_.